# .NET Core 2.0 publishing only DLL files to production server using IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Recently I made a web project using .NET Core 2.0.
And also I published the project to production server.
After that, when something is changed in Controllers or Views, I want to upload only DLL files (such as `Test.dll` and `Test.PrecompliedViews.dll`) to production server by using FTP.

Is there any ways to solve this?
I am searching how to upload only DLL files, but I can't.

Do I have to upload all the files published project from `wwwroot` folder to web.config file when I edit text in `cshtml`?

p.s. I heard dll files are holded by memory, so I can't upload only dlls.
When I restart the service's application pool in iis, I can upload only dlls.

Comment: You should try and replace the whole site every time, this will save you issues in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

There is little point in trying to re-invent the wheel here. This problem has already been solved by Microsoft - it is called [Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later).

It handles everything from picking out the *deployment assets* from the build to transferring the files to the server, to ensuring the files are not locked on the server.

IIS - [configure the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-web-deploy-when-publishing-with-visual-studio) by installing Web Deploy and setting up permissions, ports, etc.

MSBuild - Use [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) along with a [publish profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?tabs=aspnetcore2x) to push the application to the web server. There are [many options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/not-in-toc/web-publish-options) to set up a publish profile, including FTP. Alternatively, there is [tooling in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs) to publish if you would rather not use command line tools to do it.